# how to open a file by giving external command inside a subprocess call in python?

Tags: python, command, wrapper

I am able to make an external command by hardcoding the name of the file. But I want to be able to execute the command for any file.

```
execute_cmd("python sample.py")
```

Here the `execute_cmd` method takes the command "python sample.py" as an argument and Popen 's it to extract error message . Instead of giving 'sample.py', I want to specify the path of any file.
How can I do it? Or is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: How about using sys.argv?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `wrapper.py`, you can try something like this:

```
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["python", sys.argv[1]])
```

and you call it like so:

```
python wrapper.py filename.py
```

If you want to run it in your IDE, same principle you need to pass your file path as a parameter.

[image: pycharm parameter]

However, I don't think pycharm has the feature to prompt you every time for new parameters tho so you need to configure at the very bottom to make the dialog show every run

[image: pycharm show]

Comment: this works for command line. What about running it on an IDE?

Comment: How does your IDE run your wrapper script?

Comment: I'm using Pycharm community edition 2021.2 I don't know how it runs a wrapper script

Comment: Giving a parameter in the configurations still means I'm kind of hardcoding it right. My filename comes as input from user in the form of absolute file path. @JechChua

Comment: There's no other way. How can your script know which file to run?